# Bootstrap columns overlapping when shrinking page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When shrinking the screen, these images are overlapping each other. I have made no changes to the css for container-fluid or row.

```
   <div class="container-fluid bg-grey">
    <div class="row center">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="http://www.fpcbp.com/wp-content/gallery/tkGallery/OYIaJ1KK.png" width="425" height="319" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="http://www.fpcbp.com/wp-content/gallery/tkGallery/OYIaJ1KK.png" width="425" height="319" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <img src="http://www.fpcbp.com/wp-content/gallery/tkGallery/OYIaJ1KK.png" width="425" height="319" />
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

I would like the images to just stack on top of each other, instead of overlapping.

Thanks

Comment: do you have a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns will overlap because the `<img>` elements have a fixed `width` value. `col-*-*` have a set percentage width and as soon as that becomes smaller than the width set on the images, overlapping will occur.

To make images [responsive](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive) you can remove the width property and use the class `.img-responsive` so that the `<img>` doesn't exceed the width of the column. It utilizes `max-width: 100%`.

```
<img class="img-responsive" src="..." />
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked Like a charm

Comment: urg that doesn't work for me

Answer (score 0):

You should defined your columns for narrower screen, e.g. col-xs-12. It means that on screens smaller than 768px each column take all the available space, so they stack.

In your code you have 3 columns in a single row and a single column take 33.33% of available space. What's more, you have declared fixed sized of your images. In order to make them responsive, you could use Bootstrap `img-responsive` class. Notice though, that you must remove earlier fixed height and width. Otherwise images won't scale.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the two valid answers above and below did not work for you, try to add the css attributes attaching your own class to the images:

```
.myclass{max-width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <div class="container-fluid bg-grey">
    <div class="row center">
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.fpcbp.com/wp-content/gallery/tkGallery/OYIaJ1KK.png" width="425" height="319" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.fpcbp.com/wp-content/gallery/tkGallery/OYIaJ1KK.png" width="425" height="319" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.fpcbp.com/wp-content/gallery/tkGallery/OYIaJ1KK.png" width="425" height="319" />
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why this code solves the issue?